# Powershell accessing multiple parameters in a for loop

Tags: powershell, for-loop, parameter-passing

Hi I am very new to powershell and I am writing a script that accepts multiple parameters. These parameters are being accessed in a for loop inside the file.
It looks something like this

```
$numOfArgs = args.Length
for ($i=3; $i -le $numOfArgs; $i++)
{


   write-host "folder: $args[$i]"
   # does something with the arguments

}
```

However, the output gives me all the parameters as a whole instead of just one parameter specified in the array as an array element? Can someone tell me where is the mistake here? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Thanks Duncan to point this out, missing a $ in a variable.

Try this:

```
$numOfArgs = $args.Length
for ($i=3; $i -lt $numOfArgs; $i++)
{
   write-host "folder: $($args[$i])"
   # does something with the arguments
}
```

When placing a variable in a string, the variable is evaluated, not the entire expression. So by surrounding it with `$()` Powershell will evaluate the whole expression.

In other words, only `$args` was evaluated instead of `$args[$i]`

Comment: You need a `$` in the first line: `$args.Length` I tried adding it for you but it got overwritten when you improved your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The preferred Powershell way is to use a bind parameter, like this;

```
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string[]]$Paths
)

# not sure why we're skipping some elements
$Paths | foreach-object { write-host "folder: $_" }
```

Which you can specify an array or arguments, like this;

```
.\myScript.ps1 -Paths c:\,c:\Users\,'c:\Program Files\'
```

This way it will work with -argument TAB completion and will even give you a brief usage using the get-help cmdlet.

```
get-help .\myscript.ps1
myScript.ps1 [-Paths] <string[]> [<CommonParameters>]
```